# HttpPost is not fired in ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In my application there are two text boxes and one button, I want to get the text to the controller when user clicks the button.

I have tried HttpPost but it does not work, here is my code:

**View**

```
@model examplemvc1.Models.sample
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.username)
@Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.password)
<input type="submit" value"button1" />
```

**Controller**

```
namespace examplemvc1.Controllers
{
    public class sampleController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /sample/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(sample sam)
        {
            return View(sam);
        }
    }
}
```

**model**

```
namespace examplemvc1.Models
{
    public class sample
    {
        public string username { get; set; }
        public string password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `TextBoxFor` controls and submit button need to be within form tags. Use `@using(Html.BeginForm())`.  Without this, you can't POST to the controller method.

Comment: @TusharGupta i am newbie in programming please help me if my code is wrong

Comment: @markpsmith if you want then fix it as an answer i will tick it as correct answer, if you can please tell me why here a BeginForm() is needed ?

Comment: @markpsmith if you can then post an answer , i will mark it as right answer, because you are the one first inform me my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the request of the OP:

```
@model examplemvc1.Models.sample
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.username)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.password)

    <input type="submit" value"button1" />
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a form which will be posted to your controller

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBox("Name");
    @Html.Password("Password");
    <input type="submit" value="Sign In">
}
```

Produces the following form element

`<form action="/Original Controller/Original Action" action="post">`

Comment: I was writing the answer in the meanwhile no issues mate, should I remove this?

Comment: No issues @markpsmith ... It was for fun ...sorry if u felt anything :)